# Hide div class based off of a span attribute value

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

So I'm trying to write a greasemonky script, and want to toggle a particular div class based off a span value in the same tree. This will be tied to a button action.

The best I came up with is this...

> $('span[data-doc="true"]').parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().toggle();

In order to reach up the tree and hide the div class I want, I have to add all those .parent() selectors. This method also does not seem to play well with the remaining items left in the table.

I would rather do something like this, but it wont hide the div class...

> $('div.inline-block.carousel-cell)('span[data-doc="true"]').toggle();

Is there a more elegant way of hiding a particular div class based off a span value? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try `$('div.inline-block.carousel-cell:has(span[data-doc="true"])').toggle();` to do so. please check this [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/Cf7k9/2/)

Comment: Dude, you're brilliant! It worked. Thanks for the fast reply!